# Each Day need to perform same task at particular time in RPA AA

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I have implemented one small project in RPA -Automation Anywhere (A2019) on COVID19 where it capture data and store it in csv and email that to csv file to particular mail. Worked successfully.

But I need to set same task should be done everyday at particular time how can add or implement further?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the task run from the control room.

Check the official the doc:

> https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/enterprise/topics/aae-client/bot-creator/working-with-automation-tasks/using-the-schedule-manager.html

Comment: As I know in previous version AA V11.3 it was like that. For A2019 it will work same ?

Comment: its almost the same , the interface changes but same concept. Check this out: https://resources.automationanywhere.com/wistia-automation-anywhere/enterprise-a2019-how-to-schedule-a-bot